# Matching Users to Hashmap

Tags: windows, powershell

Having an issue with some PowerShell and I need some help getting put  on the right path.

We're retiring our Okta server because it's garbage, but it did some things that we needed, such as dynamic group management.

I have other scripts where I made an ordered dictionary for a GUI that I created to supplement our O365 tenant that matches locations to OU directories.

What I want to do is match all users within our designated users directory and assign people based off of that to these groups. I've created another dictionary for the Distribution Groups that I want to assign them to.

Here's what I got so far. I'm sure I'm overdoing it.

```
$TargetDGs = [ordered]@{}
$adg = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase "OU=Automagic Populating,OU=Groups"  -Filter *
$adg | % { $TargetDGs.add($_.Name, $_.DistinguishedName) }

$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq $true)} 

$sites = [ordered]@{
    'Amsterdam'             = "OU=Users,OU=Amsterdam,OU=Europe,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Atlanta'               = "OU=Users,OU=Atlanta,OU=US - East,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Boston'                = "OU=Users,OU=Boston,OU=US - East,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Charlotte'             = "OU=Users,OU=CharlotteOU=US - East,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Chicago'               = "OU=Users,OU=Chicago,OU=US - East,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Dallas'                = "OU=Users,OU=Dallas,OU=US - East,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Denver'                = "OU=Users,OU=Denver,OU=US - East,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Detroit'               = "OU=Users,OU=Detroit,OU=US - East,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Frankfurt'             = "OU=Users,OU=Frankfurt,OU=Europe,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Houston'               = "OU=Users,OU=Houston,OU=US - East,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Las Vegas'             = "OU=Users,OU=Las Vegas,OU=US - West,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN"
    'London'                = "OU=Users,OU=London,OU=Europe,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Los Angeles'           = "OU=Users,OU=Los Angeles,OU=US - West,OU=Sites,OU=MYDOMAIN";
    'Miami'                 = "OU=Users,OU=Miami,OU=US - East,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Montreal'              = "OU=Users,OU=Montreal,OU=Canada,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Nashville'             = "OU=Users,OU=Nashville,OU=US - East,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'New Jersey'            = "OU=Users,OU=New Jersey,OU=US - East,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'New Orleans'           = "OU=Users,OU=New Orleans,OU=US - East,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'New York'              = "OU=Users,OU=New York,OU=US - East,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Orange County'         = "OU=Users,OU=Orange County,OU=US - West,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Orlando'               = "OU=Users,OU=Orlando,OU=US - East,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Philadelphia'          = "OU=Users,OU=Philadelphia,OU=US - East,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Phoenix'               = "OU=Users,OU=Phoenix,OU=US - West,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'San Antonio'           = "OU=Users,OU=San Santonio,OU=US - East,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'San Diego'             = "OU=Users,OU=San Diego,OU=US - West,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'San Francisco'         = "OU=Users,OU=San Francisco,OU=US - West,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Seattle'               = "OU=Users,OU=Seattle,OU=US - West,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Toronto'               = "OU=Users,OU=Toronto,OU=Canada,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Vancouver'             = "OU=Users,OU=Vancouver,OU=Canada,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
    'Washington DC'         = "OU=Users,OU=Washington DC,OU=US - East,OU=Sites,DC=MYDOMAIN";
}
```

So the logic I'm trying to implement is

```
$TargetDGsDict
$User
$SitesDict

If ($user.DistinguishedName -like $SitesDict.Value){
AD-ADGroupMember -Identity $TargetDGsDict.Value -Member $User
}
```

So, without writing 35 if statements, how can I make this look pretty and effective? Do I even need a Dictionary? Am I overthinking this?

Comment: How do you correlate `$sites` to `$TargetDGsDict`? Are the DGs all named the same as the keys in `$sites`? If so this is super easy with a little RegEx.

Comment: They are not because AD wouldn't like that. I'm being tasked with recreating the DGs, which is otherwise easy, but we want to keep them dynamically updated. The current groups are called Los Angeles Users, Las Vegas Users, etc. They're all <City> Users. I believe I will be renaming the new TargetDGs exactly as they are now. I have $sites as a way of getting the users for that OU. I can't help but feel that I'm just wildly overthinking this

Answer (score 0):

If the DGs are all named after the parent OU of the Users OU, which I think is what the case is based on your example code, then this becomes:

```
$TargetDGs = [ordered]@{}
$adg = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase "OU=Automagic Populating,OU=Groups"  -Filter *
$adg | % { $TargetDGs.add($_.Name, $_.DistinguishedName) }

$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq $true)} 

$Users|?{$_.DistinguishedName -match 'OU=Users,OU=([^,]+),'}|%{
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $TargetDGsDict[$Matches[1]] -Member $_
}
```

That will look for the part of the user's OU that matches the group name, and reference the groups that you already created a hashtable for. It might throw errors if the user is in an OU that doesn't have an associated group though if that case exists.

Comment: Please stop using scriptblocks for the `-Filter` parameter.  It expects a string, so use one otherwise you could introduce weird bugs to your code.

Comment: I just copied the OP's example for that bit, but you're right, it should be a string not a scriptblock.

Comment: What would you suggest in the case of only wanting to have enabled users return?